# Let $X_k$ and $Y_k$ be two i.i.d. random sequences. Is the sum $Z_k = X_k+Y_k$ also i.i.d.?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, independence

> Let $X:=\{X_k\}$, $Y:=\{Y_k\}$ be two i.i.d. random sequences, and $X$ and $Y$ are mutually independent. Now,  for each $k$, we form a sum $Z_k := X_k+Y_k$. I wonder if $Z_k$ is also i.i.d. random sequence?

The sum of two independent random variables is still independent, but I am not sure about the identically distributed part.  Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: You can use the independent blocks theorem for showing independence of functions of independent random variables. The identical distribution part is sort of obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sum of indipendent variables we can express the distribution as the convolution of the individual distributions $P_{X+Y}=P_X*P_Y$. That shows that the distribution of the sum depends only on the variables distributions, hence the $X_k + Y_k$ are i.i.d.